# grep not returning all matching lines

Tags: php, grep, exec

I can't figure out how to get grep to return all lines found in a file. It counts the correct number but only prints the last match.

```
$found = array();
$term = escapeshellarg(self::$term);
foreach(self::$files as $file)
{
    if($count = exec("grep -i -c ".$term." ".$file))
    {
        $lines = exec("grep -i -n ".$term." ".$file);
        $found[] = array('count'=>$count,'lines'=>$lines,'file'=>str_replace(self::$dir, '', $file));
    }
}
self::$files = $found;
```

Let's say `self::$term = 'console.log'`. It finds three matches in one particular file, which is correct (the term appears on lines 16, 21, and 31 of a test file), but `$lines` only prints: `31:  console.log(response);`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for exec:

> Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a
>   command and have all the data from the command passed directly back
>   without any interference, use the passthru() function.

So you only get the last match that grep found, because it's the last line of output.

Comment: Is there any alternative, because passthru() seems to echo the results?

Comment: Never mind. Using `ob_start()`, `$lines = ob_get_content()` and `ob_end_clean()` is all I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope, it might help.

```
$result = array();
exec("grep '"$yourstring"' ./update.php  |  cut -d':' -f1 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'", $result);
print_r($result);
```